# c# trying to convert IEnumerable<XElement> into a List<string>

Tags: c#

I just can't figure out how to convert from IEnumerable into a List

```
public IEnumerable<XElement> GetProjects()
{
    return xd.Element("root").Element("projects").Elements();
}
```

This will give me error

```
public List<string> Projects
{
    get { return GetProjects().ToList(); }
    set { Projects_ = value; }
}

Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'
```

I could add a .Select but I feel that can be a easier way. 
Appreciate hints!

Comment: That's what Select is for....how much "easier" could it be?

Comment: I need GetProjects() to return XElements. So override GetProjects() will be the only option?

Comment: Select is the proper and easiest way to do this. GetProjects().Select(x => x.ToString()).ToList()

Comment: @user1734108: No-one suggested overriding (or overloading) `GetProjects`. Although the fact that your `Projects` setter seems to set something *entirely unrelated* to the getter functionality is distinctly worrying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the .Select:

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetProjects()
    {
        return xd.Element("root").Element("projects").Elements().Select(x => x.Value);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`Enumerable.Select` is pretty much the easiest way you can do this. See below example:

```
public List<string> Convert(IEnumerable<XElement> items) {
    return items.Select(item => item.ToString()).ToList();
}
```